# CSS Grid Layout for Posts instead of stacking (Hugo)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hugo

I'm trying to get a grid layout on the my Hugo homepage instead of the current stacked version. The posts should appear in a 3 column grid instead of the one on top of the other. To start with, I've wrapped the `<article>` tag in `list.html` in a `<div class = "container">`:

```
<div class="container">

<article class="{{ $class }}">
  {{- $isHidden := (.Site.Params.cover.hidden | default .Site.Params.cover.hiddenInList)}}
  {{- partial "cover.html" (dict "cxt" . "IsHome" true "isHidden" $isHidden) }}
  <header class="entry-header">
    <h2>
      {{ .Title }}
      {{- if .Draft }}<div class="entry-isdraft"><sup>&nbsp;&nbsp;[draft]</sup></div>{{- end }}
    </h2>
  </header>
  {{- if (ne .Site.Params.hideSummary true)}}
  <section class="entry-content">
    <p>{{ .Summary | plainify | htmlUnescape }}...</p>
  </section>
  {{- end }}
  <footer class="entry-footer">
    {{- partial "post_meta.html" . -}}
  </footer>
  <a class="entry-link" aria-label="post link to {{ .Title | plainify }}" href="{{ .Permalink }}"></a>
</article>
{{- end }}
</div>
```

I looked through the theme's CSS files and I can see that the cards for the posts are styled by `post-entry`. Combined, I've added this CSS to the `post-entry.css`:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.post-entry {
    margin-bottom: var(--gap);
    padding: var(--gap);
    background: var(--entry);
    border-radius: var(--radius);
    transition: transform .1s
    width: 32%;
    padding-bottom: 32%; /* Same as width, sets height */
    margin-bottom: 2%; /* (100-32*3)/2 */
    position: relative;
}
```

I *think* this is what it is supposed to be. But this clearly does not work. For some reason, the first post is reduced in width while the second post-entry is full-width. They are not side by side as expected but still stacked: [See the image here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6006888/103457396-fa64bf00-4d24-11eb-8a7d-13aa7ffc6012.png)

My repo is hosted here: https://github.com/thedivtagguy/archives if this is more helpful.

A live deploy is here: https://jolly-panini-82258b.netlify.app/

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your live deploy website, I see two problems:

1. The `.container` class is used for the wrapper around all posts AND for the second blog post 'Hello R Markdown'. That will cause conflicts in properly adding CSS.
2. You are setting `display: flex` on `.container`, while you really want to achieve a ***grid*** layout as per your question.

Problem 2 is easy to solve (if you have a unique class as wrapper, it will solve problem 1), you can just use `display: grid` together with `grid-template-columns` to make use of the available space and place all items on a grid. [Read more about grid-template-columns on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns).

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    margin-left: 80px;
    padding: 1px 16px;
}
```

- `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;`: how are the items divided per line, `fr` stands for fragment.
- `grid-gap`: the space between each item.

See this small snippet as starting point.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

/* Only for demonstration purposes */
.post {
  background-color: #eee;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="post">
    <h2>This is Lorem</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>Hello R Markdown</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="post">
    <h2>This is Lorem</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! I did not know about grid-templates and this definitely seems to be the easier way to do this. Based on what you said and the MDN page, I created a [three fragment template](https://pastebin.com/aM8NRXra) but if you see the [site](https://jolly-panini-82258b.netlify.app/), it seems to be adding columns instead of adding a new row after the third item. They also seem squished and not the proper width. [CSS here](https://github.com/thedivtagguy/archives/blob/master/themes/hugo-PaperMod/assets/css/post-entry.css#L15) How can I fix this?

Comment: Another user also mentioned that I'm wrapping `container` incorrectly. Where is this happening? I've added the div before `<article class="{{ $class }}">` and ended it after the closing tag. I cannot see how the second post is getting affected and yet it seems to be happening.

Comment: @namtar Probably you are adding this `.container` for each post (like in a for loop), so it might be in your Hugo templating.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach it something like this:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.post-entry-content-wrapper {
  padding: 5px;
}

.post-entry {
  width: 33.33%;
  /* etc */
}
```

And then you can just play around with the spacings.

However, I see that you are wrapping the second **.post-entry** element in another **.container** element. Take the second post-entry element out, so the second .container element doesn't interfere.

**EDIT**

To wrap the rows, you can just add `flex-wrap: wrap;` as you had in your code before.

To add some spacing, I'd just wrap the post-entry in another element and just add some padding. This is inspired by BulmaCSS.

However, since you're indeed trying to make a grid, you might as well use  `display: grid` as it's tailored for use cases like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried what you said ([see here](https://pastebin.com/ERFS8mnV) and while they are side by side now, they're clumping together without any padding (I've tried adding that too). Additionally, this should be a 3 column grid and as you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/3lJAwJ4), the fourth item does not get added in the row below and instead creates a new column.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to fit your needs a little better. However, you could indeed use display: grid.